# I need a cross-platform desktop app framework that has modern UI but also lightweight

Tags: tkinter, electron, frameworks, desktop-application

I have tried multiple frameworks such as electron and tkinter. But the first one is super heavy and the latter has a dinosaur-aged UI. any suggestions? I need something modern but without compromising speed and also has to be cross-platform.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic at Stackoverflow.

Comment: the latter - `tkinter` can easily be customized to not look like from the 90's, it is up to you tho (I have seen some GUIs that look very great and don't even seem to come from `tkinter` when if fact they do, they look incredible), however `tkinter` is not the speediest, not that the user would notice, but you won't really be able to play 4k, 120fps videos on it

Comment: You may use ttk to make tkinter look a lot better and morden.